# PeoplePicker not finding groups

Tags: people-picker

I have a client that migrated their site into a new site (different webapp). But in the new site, the peoplepicker can't find groups.

I've tried running the following in PowerShell to the old and new site, but can't find the difference.

```
$wa = get-spwebapplication "WEBAPPURL"
$wa.peoplepickersettings
```

Has this happen to anyone before?